# How remove non consecutive substrings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I' am trying to figure out how to find and delete a sub-string from a main string in javascript. For example I have the string "|1|2|3|4|5|" and I want to delete random sub-strings from this one. I made it work when i have consecutive sub-strings lets say "|1|2|", but I cant figure it out how to delete the non- consecutive sub- strings like "|1|4|". If you could help i would appropriate it.

Comment: But `"|1|4|"` is not a substring...

Comment: There are no “non-consecutive” substrings. Why don’t you just use an array? It sounds like you just want to find `1` and `4` and remove those two items.

Comment: Try running `"|1|2|3|4|5|".split('|')`. Maybe that format will be better to work with.

Comment: you can try `"|1|2|3|4|5|".replace(/(\|1\|)|(\|4\|)/g,"|")` you  get `"|2|3|5|"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with regex replace,

```
"|1|2|3|4|5|".replace(/\|(1|4)\|/g,"|")
```

you get,

```
"|2|3|5|"
```

or better,

```
function replace_non_consecutives(s, subs){
    var v = subs.match(/[^|]+/g);
    var strregex = "\\|(" + v.join("|") + ")\\|";
    var re = new RegExp(strregex,"g");
    while ( s.match(re) ) s = s.replace(re,"|");
    return s;
}

replace_non_consecutives("|1|2|3|4|5|", "|1|2|4|");
```

you get,

```
"|3|5|"
```

Comment: Hi This works perfect for non consecutive numbers in the string. But if we use |1|2| it doesn't delete the |2|.

Comment: yes, `|1|2|` don't work because 1 and 2 are consecutive numbers, I will fix it

Comment: @Kostadin i fixed overlaping problem in post

Comment: Its really funny how these copy paste warriors down vote your questions when don't ask them a question they can copy paste the answer to.